# Possible ground loop problem?

Tags: signal-integrity, ground-loop

I'm facing a strange issue and I can only think of a ground loop but the problem seems excessive. I have a three pcbs, one for some supplies, one main and one optional that can be plugged on the main board. The main and optionnal board are connected together with two mezzanine connectors that are located on opposite sides (see figure), each of them has their fair share of ground pins.

When the optionnal board is not connected, everything goes fine. When it's connected there's a communication bus on the main board that crashes.

[image]

Now what really bothers me is that I can't understand why it would cause problems to my bus if it is a ground loop issue.

The bus is controlled in impedance and really short and by short I mean traces of 1.5cm for a rise time of 1ns and a frequency of 100Mhz. Here's a screenshot of a layer with signals from the bus, it's far from perfect but I don't really feel any danger here for SI...

[image]

All of the IC's on the optionnal board should be quite inoffensive there's only things like digipots, eeproms, etc. And there's no short circuits.

I haven't seen any problems with the dedicated power supply for the bus.

The only high frequency signals on the board are USB3 signals.

The communication bus starts with some kind of synchronisation on which I don't have any control and I think this is the part that crashes because if I hot plug the board after it is done the bus still works. I can't probe the traces when the optional board is connected.

Am I missing something important here ?

Comment: What's the layer stackup on your boards?

Comment: You can probe the traces, it's just difficult. You might have to make your own passive probe from resistors/caps/cable, but it would be a good idea to get an idea of what is going on during that synchronisation. Can you probe any of the grounds? Is there significant ground bounce during that event?

Comment: I think you need to indicate if the 100MHz bus is connected from the main board to both the option board and the power board. If so there could be an impedance change in the bus when the option board is attached which results in signal reflections back toward the signal driver when the leading edge hits the impedance change point (i.e. branch point of circuits). One way this is often dealt with is to place series line impedance matching resistors in the signal line right next to the drivers.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel : 
Signal
Ground
Signal
Ground
Signal
Ground
Power
Power
Ground
Signal

Comment: @MichaelKaras Hi Michael, the bus doesn't travel board to board it's only a very short length between two IC's. I'm using integrated series resistors in the fpga for termination.

Comment: @uint128_t When all the boards are stacked, probing is nearly impossible even if you are a surgeon. Ideally do you have an advice where my probes should be ? Between the grounds of the two ics ?

Comment: Yes, checking voltage difference between grounds may give you insight on power integrity issues. And I think you can still probe the traces if you try. Worst case, you have to build an active probe onto the board, but checking signal integrity when the boards are stacked is crucial.